# Simple pure javascript image slider

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make the most simple image slider possibly in pure js, basically by changing the background position, but loop doesn't work at all. I need to repeat the loop continuously.

```
function slider1(){
var slide = document.getElementById("slider-1");
var slideWidth = 320;
var backPosY = 0;
var backPosX = 0;
var sliderEnd = 960;
var f;
for(f=backPosX;f < sliderEnd; f+=slideWidth){
    slide.style.backgroundPosition = "-"+f+"px "+backPosY+"px";
}
setInterval(slider1(),1000);}
```

Comment: can u create jsfiddle please

Comment: In your `for` loop you are basically executing everything at once. It is in the for loop that you need to set the interval.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setInterval` takes function as first parameter, but you passed `slider1()`.

Parentheses means calling function so you are calling `slider1` and passing to `setInterval` only returned value of function call.

In your case `slider1` does not return anything, that means that `setInterval` receives `undefined` instead of your function.

You need to pass the function itself, not results of its calling.

```
setInterval(slider1, 1000);
```

But be aware that every call will start a new interval and you don't want to have multiple intervals running calling the same function.

So call `setInterval` outside of your function or replace `setInterval` with `setTimeout`. Timeout will call your function once and your function will create new timeout and so on.

Edit:
Also your for loop loops through all positions in one moment. But you want to move it by one position.

I would do it like this:

```
var slide = document.getElementById("slider-1");
var slideWidth = 320;
var backPosY = 0;
var backPosX = 0;
var sliderEnd = 960;
var f = backPosX;
function slider1(){
    slide.style.backgroundPosition = "-"+f+"px "+backPosY+"px";
    f+=slideWidth;
    if(f >= sliderEnd)
        f = backPosX;
}
setInterval(slider1, 1000);
```

Edit 2: This code can be used on multiple sliders:

```
function moveSlider(slide){ // Slide is now a function parameter
    var slideWidth = 320;
    var backPosY = 0;
    var backPosX = 0;
    var sliderEnd = 960;
    if(!slide.slidePosition)    // If there isn't slidePosition in the element
        slide.slidePosition = backPosX; // Initialize it
    slide.slidePosition+=slideWidth;
    if(slide.slidePosition >= sliderEnd)    //
        slide.slidePosition = backPosX;
    slide.style.backgroundPosition = "-"+slide.slidePosition+"px "+backPosY+"px";
}

function startSlider(slide){    // Start slider's interval
    return setInterval(function(){
        moveSlider(slide);
    }, 1000);
}

function stopSlider(intervalId){    // setInterval return ID which you can use to stop the interval
    clearInterval(intervalId);
}
```

You can then start slider with:

```
startSlider(document.getElementById("slider-1"));
```

Notice that I need to pass parameter to `moveSlider`. So I wrapped in another function doesn't take any parameters and calls `moveSlider` with slider as parameter. This code example can explain it a bit:

```
function slide1(){
    ...
}
// Can be also written as:
slide1 = function(){
    ...
}
```

I just removed the middle man `slide1` and passed it directly.

Comment: Ok i remove Parentheses and set outside the function but still stop on last image/position. Can you please clarify how to use setTimeout in this case?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't address all problem your code had. I edited the answer.

Comment: Thanks. tried your code and now stop on first image/position. Cant I define the vars inside the function?  I'll have multiples sliders on page, each with different position values.

Comment: Yeah I made a mistake. I wrote f++ instead of f+=sliderWidth.
You need to store the f somewhere. If it was inside the function it would be created on the start of the function and destroyed on the end.
So you need to store it somewhere where it would persist.
One thing you can do is put it in the slider element.
slide.slidePosition = 0. I'll edit the answer to so it will support multiple sliders.